# Help with nth term divergence test on Grandi's series

Tags: sequences-and-series

For Grandi's series $1-1+1-1+\cdots$ can you use the $n$th term divergence test to prove that it diverges?

Comment: Yes.  If $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\neq 0$, then the series diverges.  If the limit doesn't exist, it still counts as not equaling $0$.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 is quite right. To say the limit is zero means (1) the limit exists, and (2) it is zero. +1 for Joe.

Comment: So when you apply the nth term divergence test to the grandi's series it would come out to a(n)=-1 which is not equal to zero, therefore the series diverges

Comment: @user218570 No.  You have $a_n=(-1)^n$.  So, you have that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(-1)^n$ does not exist.